# Convergence Rate of the Tail of the Series $m^{a}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\min\{1,2^n m^{-1} \}2^{-na}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

When $a > 0$, it's fairly easy to see that 
$$
m^{a}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\min\{1,2^n m^{-1} \}2^{-na} \leq C  \quad \forall m \in \mathbb{N},
$$
where $C$ is a finite constant independent of $m$.
How fast does the tail
$$
m^{a}\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\min\{1,2^n m^{-1} \}2^{-na} \rightarrow 0 \quad \text{as} \quad N \rightarrow \infty?
$$
Can it be bounded by a constant times $2^{-Na}$ uniformly in $m$?

The reason I suspect this is that 
$$\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} 2^{-na} = \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^{-ka}\right) 2^{-Na}.$$

EDIT: For $2^N > m$, 
$$
m^{a}\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\min\{1,2^n m^{-1} \}2^{-na} = \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^{-ka}\right) 2^{-Na} m^a 
$$
If this were bounded by $C 2^{-Na}$ for all $m,N$, taking $m,N$ such that $2^N > m > C^{1/a}$ gives a contradiction.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: The downvote is not mine, but probably it came from the fact that, quite trivially, the very last series is a geometric series, so it is not really difficult to compute.

Comment: By the very last series, you mean $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} 2^{-na}$? It is obvious this series is $O(2^{-Na})$. My question is about the second series. Is the second series obvious to compute? Am I missing something?

Comment: Once $2^N > m$, the series is just geometric, so it is $O(2^{-Na})$, so the series becomes $O((m2^{-N})^a)$.

Comment: I wasn't clear in the question that I am interested in the convergence rate uniformly in $m$. I will edit the question to make that clear.