# The $L^p$ convergence rate of the tail of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\min\{1,2^n |x|^{-1} \}2^{-na}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, lp-spaces

This a follow-up to the question: [Convergence Rate of the Tail of the Series $m^{a}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\min\{1,2^n m^{-1} \}2^{-na}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243623/convergence-rate-of-the-tail-of-the-series-ma-sum-n-1-infty-min-1-2n)

When $a > 0$, we have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\min\{1,2^n |x|^{-1} \}2^{-na} \leq C|x|^{-a}  \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, x\neq 0.
$$
where $C$ is a finite constant independent of $x$. Then for each $N$
$$
\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\min\{1,2^n |x|^{-1} \}2^{-na} \leq C|x|^{-a}  \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, x\neq 0.
$$
and for each fixed $x$
$$
\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\min\{1,2^n |x|^{-1} \}2^{-na} \rightarrow 0 \quad \text{as} \quad N \rightarrow \infty.
$$
The dominated convergence theorem implies 
$$
\left\| \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\min\{1,2^n |x|^{-1} \}2^{-na} \right\|_{L^p} \rightarrow 0 \quad \text{as} \quad N \rightarrow \infty.
$$
when $p > 1/a$.
I want to know how fast the tail converges in $L^p$. I'd like to get a bound like 
$$
2^{N(a+b)}\left\| \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\min\{1,2^n |x|^{-1} \}2^{-na} \right\|_{L^p} \rightarrow 0 \quad \text{as} \quad N \rightarrow \infty.
$$
for some $b>0$. I am most interested in the case when $1/a < p < 1/a + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is a small.

I don't think this question is trivial, but if it is please tell me how.